# Array forEach not returning boolean

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

Can someone give me some insight as to why the first 2 functions return undefined instead of a boolean?

https://jsfiddle.net/wjf2gr9d/

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

const test1Result = test1();
const test2Result = test2();
const test3Result = test3();

console.log(test1Result);
console.log(test2Result);
console.log(test3Result);


function test1() {
    return array1.forEach(x => 2 === x);
}

function test2() {
    const found = array1.forEach((x, index) => {
        if (2 === x) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return found;
}

function test3() {
    const maybeTeam = array1.find(x => 2 == x);

    return (maybeTeam) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: forEach  return undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) check return value section it returns undefined.

[image]

Foreach doesn't have any return types, You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). If you must use foreach then you can take temp variable and change it inside foreach like I did in `test2`

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

const test1Result = test1();
const test2Result = test2();
const test3Result = test3();

console.log(test1Result);
console.log(test2Result);
console.log(test3Result);


function test1() {
    return array1.some(x => 2 === x);
}

function test2() {
    var found = false;
    array1.forEach((x, index) => {
        if (2 === x) {
            found = true;
        }
       
    });

    return found;
}

function test3() {
    const maybeTeam = array1.find(x => 2 == x);

    return (maybeTeam) ? true : false;
}
```

Credits: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` always returns `undefined`; `return <arr>.forEach` will *always* result in `undefined` being returned, no matter the logic in the `forEach`. If you want to check whether any item in an array passes a particular test, you should use `.some` instead:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

const test1Result = test1();

console.log(test1Result);
function test1() {
    return array1.some(x => 2 === x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Explanation

When a function is not having explicit return in it. by default javascript function return `undefined` for that function.

For reference just look at  the example below. Here inner `console.log('hello')` is printing `hello` but since return implicit return value from inner `console.log()` is `undefined` so outer `console.log()` prints `undefined`.

```js
console.log(console.log('Hello'))
```

**Well i will suggest you look the changes.You will understand why it is so.**

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
test1();
test2();
console.log(test3());

function test1() {
    let a = array1.forEach(x => 2 === x);
    console.log(a);
    return a;
}

function test2() {
    const found = array1.forEach((x, index) => {
        if (2 === x) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    console.log(found);
    return found;
}

function test3() {
    const maybeTeam = array1.find(x => 2 == x);

    return (maybeTeam) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return a special value, depending on the inner return value from the callback. It just iterates all items.

[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or its counterpart [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns early, depending on the return value of the callback.

---

While you are using ES6, you could take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which returns a boolean, if the handed over values is part of the array.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach return undefined. what you want to use in your case is array.includes

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
function test1() {
    return array1.includes(2);
}

const test1Result = test1();


console.log(test1Result);
```