# Should I return undefined on Parse Server Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

Here is my cloud function.

Should I return undefined if the object is not found?

How about this?

```
if (results.lenth > 0) {
  return results[0].id
}
```

It is Cloud Funtion.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("todayTravelObjectId", async (request) => {
    var moment = require("moment");
    var userId = request.user.id;

    const query = new Parse.Query("Travel");

    var d = new Date();
    var start = new moment(d).startOf('day');
    var finish = new moment(start).add(1, 'day');

    //check Today Travel Object Id
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", start.toDate());
    query.lessThan("createdAt", finish.toDate());
    query.equalTo("owner", { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": userId });

    const results = await query.find();
    return (results.length > 0 ? results[0].id : undefined)

  });
```

Comment: If you don't return anything it will implicitly return undefined

Comment: You can read up here the behavior.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626763/array-foreach-not-returning-boolean/53626914#53626914

Comment: Thanks for the reply !

Comment: You could throw an error saying "object not found".